# Julia: Detect and remove duplicate rows from array?

Tags: duplicates, julia

What is the best method of detecting and dropping duplicate rows from an array in Julia?

```
x = Integer.(round.(10 .* rand(1000,4)))

# In R I would apply the duplicated function.
x = x[duplicated(x),:]
```

Comment: You do not need that `.` before `*`, `x = Integer.(round.(10 * rand(1000,4)))` works the same.

Comment: I get about a `10%` loss in speed when I switch to your method. 
`@time for i in 1:10000; Integer.(round.(10 .* rand(1000,4))); end` and
`0.991773 seconds (285.27 k allocations: 622.844 MiB, 5.71% gc time)` vs `@time for i in 1:10000; Integer.(round.(10 * rand(1000,4))); end` and `1.073937 seconds (305.08 k allocations: 928.775 MiB, 8.10% gc time)`

Comment: That's interesting! :-)

Comment: @fsmart Did you really define the `unique2` as detailed in @Gnimuc's answer? Can you add it? I would like to benchmark it

Comment: Perhaps you would also like to go with `x = rand(1:10,1000,4)`. As the calculation you made, is slower and **non-uniform** and probably has a range different from expected (it is 0,1,2... 10).

Comment: Ah, that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`unique`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/collections/#Base.unique)      <strike>is what you are looking for</strike>: (this does not answer the question for the detection part.)

```
julia> x = Integer.(round.(10 .* rand(1000,4)))
1000×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 7  3  10   1
 7  4   8   9
 7  7   3   0
 3  4   8   2
 ⋮           
julia> unique(x, 1)
973×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 7  3  10   1
 7  4   8   9
 7  7   3   0
 3  4   8   2
 ⋮
```

As for the detection part, a dirty fix would be editing [this line](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/ac714a1d118d0664890b683635cc47123aa52c22/base/multidimensional.jl#L1503):

```
@nref $N A d->d == dim ? sort!(uniquerows) : (indices(A, d))
```

to:

```
(@nref $N A d->d == dim ? sort!(uniquerows) : (indices(A, d))), uniquerows
```

Alternatively, you could define your own `unique2` with abovementioned changes:

```
using Base.Cartesian
import Base.Prehashed

@generated function unique2(A::AbstractArray{T,N}, dim::Int) where {T,N}
......
end

julia> y, idx = unique2(x, 1)

julia> y
960×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  8   3   1   5
  8   3   1   6
  1   1   0   1
  8  10   1  10
  9   1   8   7
  ⋮ 

julia> setdiff(1:1000, idx)
40-element Array{Int64,1}:
  99
 120
 132
 140
 216
 227
  ⋮
```

The benchmark on my machine is:

```
x = rand(1:10,1000,4) # 48 dups
@btime unique2($x, 1); 
124.342 μs (31 allocations: 145.97 KiB)
@btime duplicated($x);
407.809 μs (9325 allocations: 394.78 KiB) 

x = rand(1:4,1000,4) # 751 dups
@btime unique2($x, 1);
66.062 μs (25 allocations: 50.30 KiB)
@btime duplicated($x);
222.337 μs (4851 allocations: 237.88 KiB)
```

The result shows that the convoluted-metaprogramming-hashtable way in `Base` benefits a lot from lower memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

Julia v1.4 and above you would need to type `unique(a, dims=1)` where `a` is your N by 2 Array

```
julia> a=[2 2 ; 2 2; 1 2; 3 1]
4×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  2
 2  2
 1  2
 3  1

julia> unique(a,dims=1)
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  2
 1  2
 3  1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also go with:

```
duplicated(x) = foldl(
  (d,y)->(x[y,:] in d[1] ? (d[1],push!(d[2],y)) : (push!(d[1],x[y,:]),d[2])), 
  (Set(), Vector{Int}()), 
  1:size(x,1))[2]
```

This collects a set of seen rows, and outputs the indices of those already seen. This is essentially the minimal effort needed to get the result, so it should be fast.

```
julia> x = rand(1:2,5,2)
5×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  1
 1  2
 1  2
 1  1
 1  1

julia> duplicated(x)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 5

julia> x[duplicated(x),:]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 1  1
```

Comment: I really like this solution! `foldl` is something I wasn't aware of.

Comment: A small comment is that DataFrames has a `nonunique` function that does this - in fact `unique` for DataFrame rows is implemented using that `nonunique` function. So if this is public code might be a better name than `duplicated`.